# How much prime satisfy this condition?

Tags: number-theory

How much primes p exist so that $p^3-4p+9$ is a perfect square?

Of course we have p = 2, which is basically 9. I have no idea what to do now. I am trying to write it as a product a long time, but i am concluding that it is impossible if we just want integers in the product. Anyway, i don't know another method to seek the others primes.

Comment: A necessary condition for odd primes $p$ is $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ (this follows from the fact that perfect squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$). It seems $7$ and $11$ both work. The next few primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ don't seem to work however.

Comment: This problem has been posted multiple times on [AoPS](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24p%5E3-4p%2B9%24&p=1). Please use Approach0 to search for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you all. Really beautiful solution in this topic, @TobyMak.
What is this AOPS?

Comment: Art of Problem Solving: a forum for discussing contest maths questions and Olympiad problems. You should check it out if you're interested.